How is imaginatrice related to the philosophy of religion?
In the foreword to Spiritual Body, Celestial Earth, Corbin writes:

It was in Iran itself that I had to find it, in the two ages of the
spiritual world of Iran. This is why the two parts of this book are
strictly binding on one another and interdependent [1st
part=Mazdean/Pre-Islam, 2nd part=post-Islam]. A contrast due
essentially to the fact that their epistemology, foreign to this
dualism, gives room, as for the necessary mediating power, for this
agent Imagination which is imaginatrice. It is a cognitive power in
its own right. Its mediating faculty is to make us able to know
without any reservation that region of Being which, without this
mediation, would remain forbidden ground, and whose disappearance
brings on a catastrophe of the Spirit, where we have by no means yet
taken the measure of all the consequences. It is essentially a median
and mediating power, in the same way that the universe to which it is
regulated and to which it gives access, is a median and mediating
universe, an intermediate world between the sensible and the
intellectual (intelligible), an intermediate world without which
articulation between sensible and Intellectual (intelligible) is
definitely blocked. And then pseudodilemmas pullulate in the shadows,
every escape or resolution closed to them.

I can't quite follow this. I gather: religion occupies the liminal space between phenomenology and empiricism, and the author wants to bridge this gap by looking at the religious systems that bookend Iranian civilization. However, I don't understand this "imaginatrice" and why it's forbidden ground.
Is he making sense to anyone here?

It seems a neologism coined by Corbin... the word occurs only once in the English text, at page viii, without further details.

It seems that Corbin is assuming the reality of a third world, in addition to matter and soul, called mundus imaginalis and that he coined the neologism imaginatrice for the cognitive faculty that allows us to approach this new region of Being.

@MauroALLEGRANZA would you consider posting this as an answer?

What an intimidating yet fascinating way to start a book. Will need to tap into my inner masochist to finish this thing

Henri Corbin is discussing a special kind of imagination, which he calls "imaginatrice." This isn't just regular daydreaming; it's a powerful tool that allows us to perceive a specific realm of existence that lies between the physical world and the realm of pure ideas or intellect.
This "intermediate world," as he calls it, is crucial because it connects the physical and intellectual realms. Without it, there's a risk that these two realms would become completely disconnected, leading to a spiritual crisis. Corbin believes that ancient Iranian spiritual traditions understood this well, and he contrasts their approach with Western thinking, which often neglects or dismisses this vital, connecting imagination.
So, in simple terms, Corbin is saying that imagination is essential for understanding and connecting different aspects of reality. Without it, we lose a crucial part of our spiritual understanding.
